# Failed to save undefined: No COMPONENT named markup://svg found :

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

Followed the Trailhead tutorial and I still get the same error about svg.

The code I am using is taken from the Lightning Design System.
I created the supporting files as specified in the tutorial.
Here is a snippet of the Component code (just note not all the code is included since it came directly from the LDS. The error is (Failed to save undefined: No COMPONENT named markup://svg found : [markup://michelleemanuel:forecastPlanComponent]: Source). Some of the other responses I saw said to read the tutorial - I have gone down that path and it did not work. I am not invoking this from a Visualforce page but from a Component.

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal">
```

select all
        
      
      
        Opportunity Name
        
          
            
          
          Sort
        
....

Comment: I think you should check component names, may be there are some mismatch in name . also check the namespace as well. It will solve your problem.

Comment: were you able to get the SVG tab working? if yes, could you please share the details?

Comment: Okay, so I guess you have followed this link first and the issue is still persisting.
[SVG Icon Component Helper](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/lightning-svg-icon-component-helper/) Would you please try replacing `<svg>` with `<c:svg>` in your component and check?

Answer (score 16):

Starting Spring '17, the [svgIcon](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/lightning-svg-icon-component-helper/) component has been deprecated in favor of the [lightning:icon component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_icon.htm)

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:icon iconName="action:approval" size="large" alternativeText="Indicates approval"/>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer from Spring '17

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the SVG tag directly with lightning components. You'll need to make a custom component for rendering SVGs. You can copy/paste this code from the Lightning Design System Site to make your own custom SVG component:

- [Lightning SVG Icon Component Helper](https://archive-2_1_4.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/lightning-svg-icon-component-helper)

You'll need to use that component instead of the SVG tag.

Comment: Better to use the code from the Salesforce Lightning Design System site rather than Trailhead -- it's synched up with the GitHub repo, where Trailhead may not be: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/lightning-svg-icon-component-helper/

Comment: found the answer in the Lightning design system guide in that svg is not supported as defined as of now. I needed to create the svg component and then do the kludge to use it. It takes some guess work to determine the values for the attributes. I will do some more digging around the documentation to determine what works and what does not.