# Lightning List Builder - Need Working Example

Tags: lightning-aura-components, list

I am trying to build a lightning component that includes a [list builder](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/list-builder/). The example supplied does not work out of the box as it uses the depreciated [svg](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/108710/failed-to-save-undefined-no-component-named-markup-svg-found) component. There is no mention of the list builder component in the lightning or ui namespace reference doc.

I found one [snippet](https://sfbloggs.files.wordpress.com/2017/03/listbuilderinlightning.pdf) that calls itself list builder example but for me it did nothing.

What I am looking for is a working example of the above mentioned list builder component including the controller and helper files if they are required. Any assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is a bit old, but if your problem is with the svg component, you can replace it with the `<lightning:icon>` component. It will render the svg tag.

You can find more information about the icon component in the following link:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-icon/documentation

I couldn't find any reference to the List Builder component as well. What I did was to copy the HTML markup from the website you mentioned ([Lightning Design System](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/list-builder/)) and replace the svg components with the icon one.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking into this too and it appears to be a data table component. I was going through the code provided on the list builder page and it matches the output of a data table component very closely. The elements I'm trying to work through now is adding a button to a data table and having it respond similarly to the list builder example. I see you can add a button to a data table, but I haven't found how to control the onclick of the button yet.

For your specific issue of adding an icon, try using the data table as a bare component and add columns including one for an icon and it should resolve the svg issue

Comment: As of now `[lightning:datatable]`(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation) v.45.0 is not supported on mobile devices. So keep it in mind if you want to allow users to access your component via a mobile app.