# No COMPONENT error when using svg markup from Lightning Design System

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

What I'm about to ask is basically a duplicate question of [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/108710/failed-to-save-undefined-no-component-named-markup-svg-found), but the answer there seems out of date; the [URL found in the answer](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/lightning-svg-icon-component-helper/) is a broken link. I was able to find an [archive of the link](https://archive-2_1_4.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/lightning-svg-icon-component-helper) but the fact it's not current tells me I shouldn't be using that solution.

To recap, the issue I'm having is when copying/pasting code from Lightning Design Systems that contains the 'svg' tag, I get the following error when trying to save:

FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION
Failed to save comp.cmp: No COMPONENT named markup://svg found : [markup://c:comp]: Source

The [File Selector](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/file-selector/) Lightning Design code in question:

```
    <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_left" aria-hidden="true">
            <use xlink:href="/resource/SLDS252/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#upload" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
    </svg>
```

I've researched this error and understand that I need to create my own custom component that will replace svg, such as c:svgIcon. I did follow the guide in the broken link to create this custom component and then I changed the xml element in my code to c:svgIcon, but even then the code I pulled from Lightning Design includes an aria-hidden attribute, whereas the code given for the custom Lightning Component in the archived link does not include that attribute.

Can someone explain what code I can use to create the svg Custom Component such that code obtained from Lightning Design Systems will work? Is there a more recent and active walk-through guide on setting up the svg Component?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need your own *custom* SVGs, you need to create a custom renderer, as demonstrated in svgIcon. For all *standard* Lightning SVGs, use the [lightning:icon](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_icon.htm) component (or other types, such as [lightning:buttonIcon](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_buttonIcon.htm) for a button with an icon):

```
<lightning:icon iconName="utility:upload" size="xx-small" />
```

All of the SVGs in SLDS that use the "use" element can be emulated via lightning:icon and other components that use the `iconName` attribute.

I recently made a demo that shows rendering the new [Progress Ring](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/d1308608c0facdc626b85c9c248fc7af) that does not yet have a comparable Lightning component yet.

Comment: Cool, so I just replace the code from my question with the code from your answer. That seems to work, thanks! I'm just perplexed at how I should have known that (couldn't find any resources on it) or why the Lightning Design code doesn't just include the lightning:icon reference to begin with.

Comment: @TonyRush SLDS is a general-purpose design system (like Google's Material). LEX is built atop SLDS. Two different teams work on LEX and SLDS, which is why SLDS is "one release ahead" of LEX. SLDS gets updated, then the LEX team picks up those classes and packages them in to components. svgIcon was LEX team's workaround for when lightning:icon didn't exist, so once they added it, svgIcon was deprecated. I guess there should still be a document *somewhere* that explains how to use custom SVGs, but... well, here we are. I think they'll get around to it eventually.